# Can't connect to home WiFi with ESP32?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

Ok - soooooo I have this Arduino ESP32 code that has been working fine until a few days ago. Before, the below code worked fine.

```
if (wifi_ssid.length() > 0 && wifi_password.length() > 0 && clientId.length() > 0)
{
    WiFi.begin(wifi_ssid.c_str(), wifi_password.c_str());
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        delay(500);
        USE_SERIAL.print(".");
    }

    USE_SERIAL.println("");
    USE_SERIAL.println("WiFi connected");
    USE_SERIAL.println("IP address: ");
    USE_SERIAL.println(WiFi.localIP());
}
else if (count > 0)
{
    USE_SERIAL.println("MQTT Broker username, password, or client id are not saved in device preferences or are not correct. Please compelete device setup before connecting to MQTT Broker.");
    count++;
}
```

Now all of a sudden it no longer works and I get this:
WiFi connected
IP address:
0.0.0.0
....[D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:337] _eventCallback(): Event: 5 - STA_DISCONNECTED
[W][WiFiGeneric.cpp:353] _eventCallback(): Reason: 201 - NO_AP_FOUND
....
WiFi connected
IP address:
0.0.0.0
....[D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:337] _eventCallback(): Event: 5 - STA_DISCONNECTED
[W][WiFiGeneric.cpp:353] _eventCallback(): Reason: 201 - NO_AP_FOUND

What I have been able to learn is that if I create a separate const char* with data like so:

```
const char *ssid = "MyAmazingSSID";
const char *wifiPassword = "B@tman2389$";
```

and then connect to my SSID like so:

```
WiFi.begin(ssid, wifiPassword);
```

it works fine. Of course, if I try any variance of dynamically populating the ssid and password value (e.g.

```
WiFi.begin(wifi_ssid.c_str(), wifi_password.c_str())
```

or just creating a buffer from the String value and copying it over I get the old Reason: 201 - NO_AP_FOUND crap.

Anyone seen this before or have any ideas? I have pretty much wasted a weekend over this mess. What totally makes no sense is that it was working fine up until a few days ago. I didn't upgrade my WiFi library or any others for that matter.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect opportunity to learn how to use [git bisect](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect).

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks Jesper :)

Answer (score 0):

Sooooooo - since I was blocked on this started working on something else . . . came back to it this weekended. I tried my code on the MiFi and it worked fine. I then realized that the issue was my Verizon Fios modem . . . I reset it and everything works fine now. Ugh Feel like an idiot. Is there anyway we can just delete this post? I don't actually think this will be helpful to anyone else Lol